# help creating peg.js parser

Tags: javascript, parsing, expression

I am wanting to create the parser, and expression syntax in peg.js that would allow me to do these things

basically I want to pass in a mask and have a number output.

the mask has these abilities.

1) generate a random number between 0-9 (character `n` for expression? )
2) generate a random number between x and y( (x,y) for expression?)
3) literal numbers are valid (hopefully nothing needed for expession?)
4) repeat previous expression x times({x} for expression?)
5) repeat previous expression between x and y times({x,y} for expression?)

so an example expression could be

`027n(5,9){4}n12{2,8}(2,4)`

the proposed expression syntax above is only an example, it can change.

can anyone provide help in creating the parser for this in [peg.js](http://pegjs.majda.cz/online)?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The idea is to make it generate a JavaScript function, which when executed, will return a random string according to the mask.

A literal number is any character between 0 to 9, so make it generate a function that returns itself.

```
literal_number
 = num:[0-9]
 { return function() {
     return num;
 }; }
```

Then `n` is for a random number. Again, this generates a function to return a random number. I added `+ ''` to convert it to a string before returning.

```
random_number
 = "n"
 { return function() {
     return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + '';
 }; }
```

In the `(a,b)` syntax, `a` and `b` are numbers, so we need to make it parse and return a number. Using the declaration from the calculator example:

```
number
 = digits:[0-9]+ { return parseInt(digits.join(""), 10); }
```

Then we can move on to create a rule for `(a,b)` syntax.

```
random_number_between
 = "(" a:number "," b:number ")"
 { return function() {
     return a + Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1)) + ''
 }; }
```

So, these 3 things (literal_number, random_number, random_number_between) combine into a single expression that generates a valid function.

```
single_expression
 = random_number
 / random_number_between
 / literal_number
```

A single expression, followed by `{n}` or `{a,b}` forms a repeated expression. A single expression is also a repeated expression, repeated one time.

The idea of a repeated expression is, given a function, return a function that calls the input function N times, collect the result, and return it.

```
repeated_expression
 = ex:single_expression "{" n:number "}" {
       return function() {
           var result = '';
           for (var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
               result += ex();
           }
           return result;
       };
   }
 / ex:single_expression "{" a:number "," b:number "}" {
       return function() {
           var result = '';
           var n = a + Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1))
           for (var i = 0; i < n; i ++) {
               result += ex();
           }
           return result;
       };
   }
 / ex:single_expression
```

Finally, repeated expressions can be put next to each other to concatenate.

```
expression
 = list:repeated_expression* {
       return function() {
           var result = '';
           for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i ++) {
               result += list[i]();
           }
           return result;
       };
   }
```

Finally, you need a starting point, which defines a mask. This final bit scans the expression which returns a generates a function, and call it. **Put the following at the top**, and when you try it online, it will generate a string of numbers according to your mask.

```
mask
 = ex:expression
 { return ex() }
```

Example run: `027n(5,9){4}n12{2,8}(2,4)` gives `0271568891222224`.

Comment: Wow,
This should actually be in the documentation for peg.js

It's a better tutorial than what they have!

very much appreciated.

Comment: btw, I think you have a couple of rogue `11`'s in your example answer.

Comment: Hmm, im still confused a bit, I am trying to make a rule that say, if it doesnt match any other rules just return itself. how could I do that?

Comment: Oh, yes, I accidently put `11` in it.

Comment: You can also have another rule which matches any character, like `literal_char = char:.` and then return function like in `literal_number`, and append `literal_char` to `single_expression` rule to make it accept `literal_char`.

Comment: ah! the . is what I was missing! I had it working by modifying the literal_number to accept [0-9a-z+,.....]